# All Kubernetes pods run in a single CPU

Tags: kubernetes

My machine has 48 CPUs. Before creating pods, I offline 1-47 CPUs by `echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpuN/online`.

When I create the first pod to a node, I online CPU `#1` by echo `"1" > /sys/devices/system/cpu1/online`. The pod run CPU stress task and I see `CPU0` is fully used by this pod. The pod use `99-100% CPU`.

When I create the second pod to the same node, I online `CPU #2 echo "1" > /sys/devices/system/cpu2/online`. But only CPU0 is fully used, `CPU1` and `CPU2` didn't have load. And both pod run with 50% CPU usage.

If I create more pods to the same node, they just share `CPU0` whatever I online more CPUs. All other online CPUs are just idle.

My `Kubernetes version is 1.23.12`. This doesn't happen in version `1.28`. In version `1.28`, all pods run in different CPUs with 100% usage. Pod's yaml have CPU limitation and request to 1.

I am not sure this is a bug in version `1.23.12` or some configuration goes wrong in it. Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/releases/

Answer (score 1):

The CPU Manager is responsible for the allocation of `CPU` resources to pods in Kubernetes. On a node, the CPU Manager is responsible for enabling enhanced workload policies. For example, depending on whether the pod is throttled and which CPU cores are available at scheduling time, it directs multiple `CPU`-intensive pods to share tasks to different CPU cores.

CPU Manager has been in beta since Kubernetes `v1.12` and is enabled by default. The `--cpu-manager-policy` kubelet option is employed to define the CPU Manager policy.

In [Kubernetes version 1.23.14](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#v12314) they have a [fix for a bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#bug-or-regression-3) in the change.

```
Kubelet: fix GetAllocatableCPUs method in cpumanage.
```

From [version 1.26](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/12/27/cpumanager-ga/), the CPU manager went GA in Kubernetes. This means that the CPU Manager feature has been deemed stable and is ready for use in production environments. So that might be the reason you are getting an issue in `version 1.23.12` not in `version 1.31`.